# Is "get hairs cut" proper English?

Tags: word-usage, usage

A friend always writes in her emails that she and her husband are going to get their “hairs cut at a salon”, not hair cuts or haircuts. She grew up in the 1930s in L.A. so perhaps this was normal for that era but it seems awkward. I would never correct her but I would like to know if this is correct English.

Comment: It's not idiomatic. to get [my, your] hair cut, is idiomatic. To get my clothes cleaned [dry cleaned]. To get my work done.

Comment: Note that the phrase is *literally* correct, even though it's unusual. You do *actually* have hairs cut. It could also be said in a joking way. An expression that was once said in jest but has since become habit.

Answer (score 2):

That does not sound right to me. In current LA, I'm sure they don't say that. 1930s: I *doubt* it, but wasn't there.

Possibly she is making a private joke. I have heard people (mostly women) saying that their husband will get his "hairs" cut, implying that he has so little hair left, that when the barber cuts "**it**", he actually cuts "**them**" (one at a time).   ...[impertinent question: is her hair thinning also?]

Comment: It's also not impossible that she (pedantically or jocularly) employs the plural because she's getting her hair cut and he's getting his hair, so two hairs are cut.:)

Answer (score 2):

"Hairs cut" is not idiomatic.  It should be "haircuts".

However, there is a silly joke (one we might call a ["Dad joke"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dad_joke)) that relies on the ambiguous relationship between the uncountable noun "hair" (the part of the body that refers to the *quantity* of hair on one person's head) and the countable noun "hair" (as in a *strand* of hair):

> Son:  Hey Dad, can I have some money to get a haircut?
>   Dad:  How much do you need?
>   Son:  It's $20.
>   Dad:  Well for that price you'd better tell them to cut more than one hair.

Your friend might also be making a joke, or it might be a common expression used by her friends and family.